# Grow div width depending on table width that is inside it

Tags: html, css, html-table, internet-explorer-7

I am dealing with an issue in Internet Explorer 7.

I want to make the container div wider enough that a long table fit inside it. What I am getting now, is a div with a width according to window size and table overflowing this div.

Here is my code, I hope that I have been clear in the explanation given.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" >
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border:1px solid red; width:100%; table-layout: fixed;">
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="166" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="167" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="168" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="169" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="170" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="171" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="172" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="173" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="174" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="175" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="176" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="177" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="178" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="179" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="180" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="181" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="182" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="183" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="184" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="185" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="186" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="187" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="188" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="189" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="190" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="191" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="192" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="193" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="194" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="195" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="196" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="197" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="198" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="199" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="200" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="201" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="202" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="203" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="204" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="205" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="206" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="207" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="208" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="209" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="210" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="211" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="212" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="213" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="214" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="215" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="216" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="217" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="218" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="219" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="220" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="221" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="222" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="223" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="224" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="225" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="226" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="227" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="228" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="229" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="230" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="231" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="232" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="233" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="234" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="235" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="236" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="237" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="238" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="239" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="240" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="241" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="242" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="243" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="244" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="245" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="246" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="247" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="248" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="249" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="250" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="251" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="252" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="253" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="254" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="255" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="256" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="257" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="258" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="259" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="260" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="261" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="262" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="263" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="264" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="265" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="266" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="267" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="268" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="269" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="270" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="271" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="272" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
      <td>
        <textarea wrap="OFF" tabindex="273" cols="11" rows="4" name="cell"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

try removing the "width:100%" ... you're setting that div to be only the width of the window, I assume you want it to expand and your window will have horizontal scroll bars.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="border:1px solid red; float:left;">
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9hFsp/

Comment: Your solution is great. But now, if I resize the window (because this content is shown inside a Popup), in other words, if I "maximize", the Div and table are not growing and stil having the width before maximize (only in firefox). If I add width: 100%, it brokes my first purpose (container width = table width) in Internet Explorer...